# Downloading images in a jsp: Illegalstateexception: getwriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, illegalstateexception

First of all, sorry if this question has already been asked, I have seen a lot of similar questions but none of them provide me an useful answer.

I'm using Struts and I want to download an image into a img tag. I use this in other places of my application and works fine, but in one of them the action throws IllegalStateException. It is a login page, there's nothing special about it. This is the code in the action where the exception is thrown:

```
public String mappingExecute(ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    String idDocumento = request.getParameter("idDocumento");
    FileResponse fResponse = WebConfig.getFileManager().downloadFile(idDocumento);

    byte[] buffer = fResponse.getFileByteArray();
    out.write(buffer);
    out.close();
    return null;

}
```

and this is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:183)
at net.bilbao.dxd.web.SrvDownloadFile.mappingExecute(SrvDownloadFile.java:22)
at net.bilbao.dxd.web.SrvAction.execute(SrvAction.java:56)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

(SrvDownloadFile is the name of my action class, exception is thrown at `response.getOutputStream()`)

Here is the weird part: When I log on, the next jsp calls the same action and the image shows fine. When I return to login page, then the image shows fine too! This exception is only thrown the first time you go to the login page. Is there something I could do to check where `getWriter()` is called before my action call it?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in login action you are forwarding the response and by the time the control comes to the line the response has already been sent and that is what the exception is telling you.
In other instances may be this login action is not called so it works as expected.